# How do you keep print formatting of a string without printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a variable that is perfectly formatted with print, but looks terrible without it. I'm trying to pass it to a function as the body of an email for python to send, but it doesn't format correctly. Is there a function that lets it see /n etc in the string and convert it to another string?

The function to send the email is:

```
from mochila import Email
def send_mail(from_email, email_group, subject_text, body_text, attachment=None):
        """
        Function to send emails.
        Inputs:
            - email_group: comma separated string of emails to send message to; str
            - attachment: Location of attachment to send; str
            - subject_text: Subject of the email; str
            - body_text: Body of the email; str
        """
        if attachment == None:
            email = Email(
                to_email=email_group,
                from_email=from_email,
                body=body_text,
                email_type='html',
                subject=subject_text)
        else:
            email = Email(
                to_email=email_group,
                from_email=from_email,
                body=body_text,
                email_type='html',
                subject=subject_text,
                attach=[attachment])
        email.send()
```

Without print:

```
System Status Update Complete Min Date: 2022-07-17 Max Date: 2022-07-17 Summary: var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 count 1905.000000 1905.000000 1905.000000 1905.000000 1905.000000
```

With print:

```
System Status Update Complete
Min Date: 2022-07-17
Max Date: 2022-07-17
Summary:
              var1         var2         var3          var4          var5
count  1905.000000  1905.000000  1905.000000   1905.000000   1905.000000
```

Comment: Can you snip the code ?

Comment: How are getting the contents of the string when you *aren't* printing it? You should already see lots of additional whitespace and `\n` in the contents, not the string you show above.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb, but I'm guessing that your email is HTML format.  That's the problem.  HTML compresses all whitespace and newlines.  You can try using `<pre>` before and `</pre>` after to signal that it is preformatted.

Comment: Wouldn't the other option to be to not set email_type to 'html'?

Comment: I'm not sure. All of the links to this package appear broken on readthedocs.org right now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `<pre>` before and `</pre>` after as @TimRoberts suggested in the comments did format it correctly.

I forgot that the passed string was being interpreted as HTML. Hopefully this answer saves somebody some effort in the future.

```
def send_mail(from_email, email_group, subject_text, body_text, attachment=None):
    """
    Function to send emails.
    Inputs:
        - email_group: comma separated string of emails to send message to; str
        - attachment: Location of attachment to send; str
        - subject_text: Subject of the email; str
        - body_text: Body of the email; str
    """
    if attachment == None:
        email = Email(
            to_email=email_group,
            from_email=from_email,
            body='<pre>'+body_text+'</pre>',
            email_type='html',
            subject=subject_text)
    else:
        email = Email(
            to_email=email_group,
            from_email=from_email,
            body='<pre>'+body_text+'</pre>',
            email_type='html',
            subject=subject_text,
            attach=[attachment])
    email.send()
```